# How to get one ( representative) number from 2 sensors with many measurements

Tags: statistics, average

I have 2 temperature sensors in a field gathering data 24h every day (every half an hour frequency). For instance I want to pick a day. On Friday I have 48 measurements from T1 sensor and 48 measurements from T2 sensor. If I calculate the average of T1 values in the morning hours and get `avg_T1`. Then I calculate average of T2 sensor in the morning hours and get `avg_T2`. So, until now I have 2 numbers. Then, I get the average of `avg_T1` and `avg_T2` and have the `avg_T`. Can `avg_T` be a representative number of the field of day Friday for an average temperature that characterizes the field those specific morning hours? Can it stand from a scientific point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have equal confidence in the reliability of the two sensors and equal confidence in their accuracy at different times then your best average for all the observations is their average, which you can calculate as the average of the two separate averages.

Whether this can "stand from a scientific point of view" depends on what you want to use that average for. The answer might depend on how much variation there is in the measurements. I can imagine that averaging the midnight and noon temperatures might not make sense. So this question does not have a mathematical answer.